# Pricing Futures with Short Sell Restrictions and Borrowing/Lending Costs

Tags: futures

From the book "Derivatives for the trading floor" by Patrick Boyle, it has no answers, so I'm curious as to what they are.

In a free market from transaction costs, arbitrage opportunities, taxes, or restrictions from short selling, what would the fair price be for an oil futures contract if the spot oil is trading at $50, the risk-free rate is 5% (compounded semi-anually), and expiration is six months away?

Using the equation in the book:

[image: Futures Equation]

The follow up question is as follows:

Working from the limitation in the last question, if restrictions on short selling meant that a reverse cash-and-carry trader (one who is long the futures contract simultaneously short the underlying asset) could only receive the use of 85% of the proceeds of oil sold short, what is the permissible range of oil futures prices?

And also:

Taking all of the information in the last two questions into account, if borrowing cost was 5%, but the lending rate was 4.5% (both compounded semi-annually), what now would be the permissible range of oil futures prices?

Thanks in advance, FYI, this isn't an assignment or anything, just self studying, but not sure how to solve these.

Comment: Probably better suited for https://quant.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DStanley I asked the same questions on quant, but it got deleted for being to "basic"  :(